# Writing on notes a value from another cell automatically through App Script [Google Sheet]

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a specific value on the notes of all the cells of a specific column, but since notes don't support formulas I'm trying to get this through Apps Script.

I'm new to it so I'm still kinda clueless about the syntax and I can't find a proper example of what I wanna do.

I made this, which is actually creating a note when I edit any cell in the 12th column but the value reported on the note is "Range" instead of what I'm expecting (the value of the cell on the 13th column).

```
 function onEdit(e) {
   if(e.range.columnStart === 12){
   var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
   cell.setNote(cell.offset(0,0));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, how about the following modification? `offset` returns the Class Range. So in this case, `getValue` is used for retrieving the value.

#### From:

```
cell.setNote(cell.offset(0,0));
```

#### To:

```
cell.setNote(cell.offset(0, 1).getValue());
```

- In this modification, the value of the neighbour to the right cell is retrieved and set it as a note. So, from `if (e.range.columnStart === 12) {}`, in this case, the value of column "M" is retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: @Antonio Carta Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.